# Positioning div to botton right from css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Here i have a carousel. i need to position booton right the container NOIMAGE, the parent container should be .carousel-inner.

```
<div class="list-offers">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row1">
    <div class="col-xs-12 item bg_fix right" style="background-image: url(&quot;./images/bottom.jpg&quot;);">
     <img class="foto" alt="Beach" title="Beach" itemprop="image" src="./images/bottom.jpg" style="display: none;">
     <div class="col-xs-12 item ">
      <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel2">
       <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item  noimage">
         <h4 itemprop="name">¡consectetuer adipiscing elit!</h4>
         <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="item   noimage active">
         <h4 itemprop="name">¡consectetuer adipiscing elit!</h4>
         <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="item   noimage">
         <h4 itemprop="name">consectetuer adipiscing elit!</h4>
         <p itemprop="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
       </div>
     </div>
     <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#myCarousel2"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#myCarousel2" class="active"></li>
      <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#myCarousel2" class=""></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is what i have intend. taking the 2 containers and trying to styling it properly, but unsuccessfully no works

```
.carousel-inner {
    background-color: aqua !important;
    position: relative !important;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21
}

.noimage {
    /*display: flex;*/
    position: absolute !important;
    bottom: 0 !important;
    right: 0 !important;
    width: 600px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to add a button at the right bottom of your carousel. If so, the demo shows the Bootstrap carousel where I've positioned the button as absolute inside the parent carousel-inner container as you wanted. But, I've kept the original carousel-inner properties and not interfered with these.

```css
.rightBtn {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: teal;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300?image=28" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300?image=29" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://picsum.photos/300?image=30" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
    <span class="rightBtn">button</span>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```